# xxx.eot web font file won't work properly on IIS 6.0 server

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, internet-explorer-8, eot

I'm using two web fonts 'NanumGothic.eot'

and 'NanumGothic.woff', with CSS style like below.

This system is hosting web services, based on Windows Server 2003

and IIS 6.0 and local remote MS-SQL Server 2008.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: ngweb;
        src:url('NanumGothic.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
}
@font-face {
        font-family: ngie;
        src:url('NanumGothic.eot'); /* IE6-IE8 */
}
```

.woff file works fine at NON-IE 6, IE 7, and IE 8 web browsers, even on IE 9(works fine here).

From IE 6 to IE 8, they are works with .eot font file that I know.

But, this server doesn't present web font at all(on IE 6 ~ IE 8).

My IE 8 browser security setting is enabled web font downloadable.

Other similar system's are service same .eot file in good way.

I searched on Google, about sytle CSS tag and applied them on the system, but there's no improvements.

Why do this to me MS???

Server system reboot could solve this problem? really?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for IIS6 but in IIS7 you need to add a mime type for the font. Have you looked into this?